# Python appears to be dying before it finishes looping through these Hex values. How fix?

Tags: python, memory, loops

```
def generate_macs():
    for i in xrange(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF + 1):
        mac = hex(0x000000 + i)[2:].upper()
        mac = [mac[x:x + 2] for x in range(0, len(mac), 2)]

        yield ':'.join(mac)

for mac in generate_macs():
    print 'E8:06:88:{0}'.format(mac)
```

I'm trying to generate a list of the MAC addresses between `E8:06:88:00:00:00 and E8:06:88:FF:FF:FF`.

The program seems to be dying at this line:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tail range1.txt
E8:06:88:44:86:55
```

Why...? :/

Comment: It consistently dies at the same place?  Do you only need the list generated once?  What happens when you change your xrange to only do 0x448650 to 0x44865F?  Is this the exact code you are using?

Comment: You still haven't said what you need these for. You realize the full output will be close to 300MB, yes?

Answer (score 5):

First, your generator function there doesn't output a full MAC address before it gets to the third digit; I solved that by using the following code:

```
def generate_macs_2():
    for a in range(0, 0x100):
        for b in range(0, 0x100):
            for c in range(0, 0x100):
                yield "{0:02X}:{1:02X}:{2:02X}".format(a, b, c)

for mac in generate_macs_2():
    print 'E8:06:88:' + mac
```

It also returns the MAC addresses in the order of lowest to highest, in terms of numerical value, in uppercase, and is simpler to look at and understand at a glance (IMHO).

For completeness, and because it was mentioned below, here is how to do it with `itertools.product`:

```
def generate_macs_3():
    for item in itertools.product(range(0, 0x100), repeat = 3):
        yield "{0:02X}:{1:02X}:{2:02X}".format(item[0], item[1], item[2])

for mac in generate_macs_3():
    print 'E8:06:88:' + mac
```

The OP's runs in ~40 seconds on my system, my first one runs in ~26 seconds average, and the second one (using `itertools`) takes about ~32 seconds average.

Comment: This would be made neater still by using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: I'm pretty new to Python, so I haven't checked out any of itertools just yet, it is on my list though.  Also, this version seems to run nearly 40% faster than the OP's version...

Comment: Ah, that is nice.  Got it with `itertools.product` and that is cool, though seems to be about 8 seconds slower than the nested for loop above.  Also interesting; I'd have expected it to be faster, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Trausch has some good ways of generating these, but if you're worried about speed, then here is probably about as fast it can be done with pure Python without using multiprocessing (which could really speed this up):

```
import sys
def generate_macs():
    localf = "E8:06:88:{0:02X}:{1:02X}:{2:02X}\n".format
    localx = xrange(0,0x100)
    sys.stdout.writelines([localf(a,b,c) for a in localx \
                          for b in localx for c in localx])
```

That takes, on my computer, about 53%  less time than the fastest generator solution in Michael's post. Of course, if you don't have the memory to generate them all as a list before writing them out(as in my code), then you can take out the brackets (which then makes it into a generator expression) and the code is only about 39% faster.

Anyway, you probably don't need to generate this very often so speed isn't very important, but if it is, then there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

The macs aren't being returned in the order you're expecting. I just ran the code and got this:

```
furby:playground jonesy$ grep 'FF:FF:FF' macs.txt 
E8:06:88:FF:FF:FF
```

Comment: The generator yields the mac's in order (aside from the issue of leading zeros) I suspect this is not the exact code that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what happens when it stops?

Also, you may have more luck replacing

```
mac = hex(0x000000 + i)[2:].upper()
```

with

```
max = "%06X"%i
```

it solves the leading zero problem

Comment: It gets to a certain point and just stops. No errors, just nothing. I can't ctrl+c to escape either. Have to kill the terminal.

Comment: @charles, can you tell us more about the environemnt? which Python version? are you running on a local machine? Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Python 2.6.5 on an Ubuntu 10.04.1 LiveCD. Using /bin/bash

Comment: @charles, is the file being written to RAM then? perhaps you don't have enough free ram to hold the whole file

Comment: @charles Try piping your program's output to tail; you'll see that yours works.  But it generates (in yours and my two forms) 16.7 million MAC addresses, 18 bytes each, for an output file 301,989,888 bytes long.  Running from Live CD would mean that you need that much RAM to hold it, and that RAM has to be allocated to the union filesystem that things are running on.

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by this problem and wanted to explore generating arbitrary ranges.
I found that hex formatting seems to be the bottleneck and string formatting/concatenation in general.

There are ways that this code below could be further optimized. Aside from that I wanted dable with lookup tables and bitwise operations.

These solutions use about 10MB of ram at runtime.  If the list was materialized using a list comprehension it uses over 1GB and takes longer...

My best solution so far, pre computes hex encodings into a list.  2 Hex ranges are encoded per lookup table to avoid the hit of string formatting.  If I tried to use more Hex digits in a string the lookup table got too big and also tool longer to generate than the functions took to run.

**Fastest one because it handles about half as many strings**

```
from itertools import product

def generate_macs(first, last):
    begin = int(first.replace(':', ''), 16)
    end = int(last.replace(':', ''), 16) + 1
    look_co = ['%02X:%02X:' % i for i in product(xrange(0x00, 0x100), repeat=2)]
    look_ln = ['%02X:%02X\n' % i for i in product(xrange(0x00, 0x100), repeat=2)]

    return ( look_co[i >> 32 & 0xFFFF] + \
             look_co[i >> 16 & 0xFFFF] + \
             look_ln[i & 0xFFFF] for i in xrange(begin, end))
```

Other versions use string formatting or 2hexdigit groupings string concatenated.

**Pure Hex Formatting**

```
def generate_macs(first, last):
    begin = int(first.replace(':', ''), 16)
    end = int(last.replace(':', ''), 16) + 1

    return ( '%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n' % (
                i >> 40 & 0xFF,
                i >> 32 & 0xFF,
                i >> 24 & 0xFF,
                i >> 16 & 0xFF,
                i >> 8 & 0xFF,
                i & 0xFF) for i in xrange(begin, end))
```

**2Hex Digits per lookup string concated**

```
def generate_macs(first, last):
    begin = int(first.replace(':', ''), 16)
    end = int(last.replace(':', ''), 16) + 1
    look_co = ['%02X:' % i for i in xrange(0x00, 0x100)]
    look_ln = ['%02X\n' % i for i in xrange(0x00, 0x100)]
    return ( look_co[i >> 40 & 0xFF] + \
             look_co[i >> 32 & 0xFF] + \
             look_co[i >> 24 & 0xFF] + \
             look_co[i >> 16 & 0xFF] + \
             look_co[i >> 8 & 0xFF] + \
             look_ln[i & 0xFF] for i in xrange(begin, end))
```

**2Hex Digits per lookup string join**

```
def generate_macs(first, last):
    begin = int(first.replace(':', ''), 16)
    end = int(last.replace(':', ''), 16) + 1
    look_co = ['%02X:' % i for i in xrange(0x00, 0x100)]
    look_ln = ['%02X\n' % i for i in xrange(0x00, 0x100)]
    return ( ''.join((look_co[i >> 40 & 0xFF],
             look_co[i >> 32 & 0xFF],
             look_co[i >> 24 & 0xFF],
             look_co[i >> 16 & 0xFF],
             look_co[i >> 8 & 0xFF],
             look_ln[i & 0xFF])) for i in xrange(begin, end))
```

Code used to run it

```
f = open('foobar.txt', 'w')
f.writelines(generate_macs('E8:06:88:00:00:00', 'E8:06:88:FF:FF:FF'))
f.close()
```

The other solutions offered by Justin and Michael are both infinitely more readable/maintainable.
Michaels uses 4MB or ram on my machine. Justin's uses 1GB with it's List Comprehension and only 4MB if replaced with a Generator Expression (as he mentioned).
Mine use 10MB and runs about Twice fast, cost the Client probably 10 times as much and will continue to in the future.

The metrics used for performance was disk i/o in os/x's Activity Monitor and Mississippis.

**EDIT: New winner.**

**Fastest**
This one really screams and uses 4.1MB of ram. Generates output to /dev/null in 2 seconds.

```
def generate_macs():
    from operator import add
    from itertools import product
    heads = [ 'E8:06:88:%02X:%01X' % i for i in product(xrange(0, 0x100), xrange(0, 0x10))]
    tails = [ '%01X:%02X\n' % i for i in product(xrange(0, 0x10), xrange(0, 0x100))]
    return starmap(add, product(heads, tails))
```

**Second Fastest**
almost as fast as the one above, arguably more readable. 4.1MB. Generates output to /dev/null in 3 seconds

```
def generate_macs():
    from itertools import product
    hexs = [':%02X' % h for h in xrange(0, 0x100)]
    return imap(''.join, product(('E8:06:88',), hexs, hexs, hexs, ('\n',)))
```

**Conclusion**

- My final solutions have no lookup tables and no bitwise operations.
- There are interesting uses for *product* as introduced by the other posters.
- Any time you can use implied loops and push things down to c (as I understand it) do.
- Format less, often.